# Visual studio 2010 adding SL project reference in non-SL project results in warning icon

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight class library project which is referenced (project reference) in Windows Console project. 
In visual studio 2010, I see warning icon next to the referenced project. I am using SL4 and .net 4.0.

When I build and run the console project, it works perfectly fine. I understand that silverlight library project can be referenced in Windows Console project or WPF project.

Will the warning cause any side effects? Do I have to take any corrective actions? Thanks. Screen capture attached.

[image]

Warning message 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010: Warning on add project reference to Silverlight project from .NET project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792207/vs2010-warning-on-add-project-reference-to-silverlight-project-from-net-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's by design. see:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557761/adding-a-project-reference-to-a-silverlight-project-from-a-net-project-results-in-misleading-warning

> References between different
>   frameworks is not supported, which is
>   why you get the warning. This is
>   because you will see runtime failures
>   with projects that have references
>   across different frameworks.

and a previous SO question:

[VS2010: Warning on add project reference to Silverlight project from .NET project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792207/vs2010-warning-on-add-project-reference-to-silverlight-project-from-net-project)